# visual basic hashtable image key/value

Tags: .net, vb.net, hashtable

What I want to achieve with this question is to get the random name generated from an array of strings for that particular *EnemyName* chosen to correspond with the *eneImage.key* and then return the value into a string(if possible) to then send that too the Form requesting the information.

I will post the whole code for the interested people [Whole code, pastebin](http://pastebin.com/9PYnW5Ty)

So I have a hashtable like below:

```
Private eneImage As New Hashtable()

Sub Main()
    eneImage.Add("orc", My.Resources.orc)
    eneImage.Add("troll", My.Resources.troll)
    eneImage.Add("salamander", My.Resources.salamander)
    eneImage.Add("cavetroll", My.Resources.cavetroll)
    eneImage.Add("dragon", My.Resources.dragon)
    eneImage.Add("vampire", My.Resources.vampire)
    eneImage.Add("werewolf", My.Resources.werewolf)
End Sub
```

And then I have a `for` function that includes a for each loop that iterates through the hashtable:

```
Private eImage As Bitmap

Public Function getEnemyImage() As Bitmap

    For Each de As DictionaryEntry In eneImage
        MsgBox("Key = {0}, Value = {1}", de.Key, de.Value)
    Next de
```

Currently not using this one below because it chooses the image at random and the name is random aswell.

```
    'For i As Integer = n1 To n2
        'If i = GetRandom(n1, n2) Then
            'eImage = enemyImage(i)
        'End If
    'Next i
    Return eImage
End Function


Public Function getEnemyName() As String
    InitMonsters()
    n1 = LBound(enemyName)
    n2 = UBound(enemyName)

    For i As Integer = n1 To n2
        If i = GetRandom(n1, n2) And Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(enemyName(i)) Then
            eName = enemyName(i)
        End If
    Next i
    Return eName
End Function
```

---

I used the answer that was given below and it works perfectly.

```
Private eName As String
Private eImage As Image
Private eneImage As New Dictionary(Of String, Image)

Private Sub initImages()
    If Not eneImage.ContainsKey("orc") Then
        eneImage.Add("orc", My.Resources.orc)
        eneImage.Add("troll", My.Resources.troll)
        eneImage.Add("salamander", My.Resources.salamander)
        eneImage.Add("cavetroll", My.Resources.cavetroll)
        eneImage.Add("dragon", My.Resources.dragon)
        eneImage.Add("vampire", My.Resources.vampire)
        eneImage.Add("werewolf", My.Resources.werewolf)
    End If
End Sub

Public Function getEnemyName() As String
    eName = [Enum].GetName(GetType(Enemies), GetRandom(1, 7))
    Return eName
End Function

Public Function getEnemyImage()
    initImages()
    For Each de As KeyValuePair(Of String, Image) In eneImage
        Dim m As String = de.Key
        Dim n As String = eName.ToLower
        If m.StartsWith(n) Then
            eImage = de.Value
        End If
    Next de
    Return eImage
End Function
```

Comment: Just how is a HashTable storing a Key Value pair?  And you wanna check your spelling?   And why GetRandom in the loop?

Comment: From what I've read HashTable stores Key and Value, dunno how you mean. My english is very bad so no excuse there, the GetRandom is only there too give a random number between let say 1 and 10. But I dont wanna print out a random image everytime I fight a random monster. I want to make it so that I get a random name from the string array I have with entrys(which works just fine) then compare that name with the hashtable Key and see if it's the same if so, print the image to the PictureBox.

Comment: My bad.  I confused HashTable with HashSet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want is an Enum of Enemies that will allow you to translate the random number to an enemy name.  Then using a dictionary will allow you to store the images as images instead of as objects:

```
Enum Enemies
    werewolf = 1
    orc = 2
    salamander = 3
    troll = 4
    cavetroll = 5
    dragon = 6
    vampire = 7
End Enum
Private eneImage As New Dictionary(Of String, Image)
Sub Main
    eneImage.Add("orc", My.Resources.orc)
    eneImage.Add("troll", My.Resources.troll)
    eneImage.Add("salamander", My.Resources.salamander)
    eneImage.Add("cavetroll", My.Resources.cavetroll)
    eneImage.Add("dragon", My.Resources.dragon)
    eneImage.Add("vampire", My.Resources.vampire)
    eneImage.Add("werewolf", My.Resources.werewolf)
    Dim rnd1 As New Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond)
    Dim enemyname As String = [Enum].GetName(GetType(Enemies), rnd1.Next(1, 7))
End Sub
```